# Odoo 13 PDF Some blank pages if the number of record increased

Tags: python, pdf, odoo, qweb, odoo-13

I have this strange problem while downloading the custom pdf report. If I download my custom report for 30 records (also contains two logo png and one personnel image in the report) then there is no problem. But when the number of records increased say it 50 or above, some pages are good but some are blank and some only contain borders and logos and not contents. I searched a lot and tried a lot but didn't come with a solution.

Anyone can help me regarding this

Thank you in advance